# Criteria query for outer join to subquery

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have two tables, tableA and tableB:

```
tableA: int id, String val
tableB: int id, String logs, int a_ref.
```

I need to create a query such as:

```
SELECT tabB.* FROM tableB tabB
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableA tabA ON tabA.id = tabB.a_ref;
```

But I can't change the metadata (modify the Hibernate mapping files (`.hbm`) for the respective tables).

How to create a criteria query in hibernate for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A HQL or Criteria query is based on entities and relationships between entities, and you didn't show us you entities, so we can only speculate. If `TABLEA` is mapped to `TableA` and `TABLEB` is mapped to `TableB`, with a many-to-one association between TableB and TableA, then the query is obvious:

```
select b from TableB b left join b.tableA
```

But note that the left join is completely useless here, since it doesn't add any restriction to the query, and the query doesn't select anything from `TABLEA`. Your initial SQL query should very well be written as `select tabB.* from TABLEB tabB`. And the criteria query would thus just be

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(TableB.class)
```

Comment: There is no association between TableA and TableB in the hbm file.

Comment: Then you won't be able to do a join without using a native SQL query or fixing the mapping.

Comment: Can i create a query something like this:-

select tabB.* from TABLEB tabB
left outer join (select tabA_.ID from TABLEA tabA_) refer on refer.ID = tabB.a_ref;

Comment: in HQL, AFAIK, no. In Criteria, definitely, no.